# linking between tables in abap data dictionary

Tags: sap-erp

I am learning abap, I am unable to build the logic without knowing the table linking in abap, but I know the related fields.

(LIPS-VGBEL = VBAK-VBELN, LIPS-VGPOS = VBAP-POSNR) this all are different fields how this are equal please clarify my doubt.

Comment: Didn't get your question though. What do you imply under linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equal, because they have the same domain.

Go to se11 -> lips -> vgbel -> column data elemnt vgbel 
If you are doubleklicking, you see, that the domain is `vbeln`

This is the same domain like the domain of the vbak-vbeln.
It's the same with vbap-posnr and lips-vgpos.

It's still the same domain.

I hope it helped...

Answer (score 0):

This knowledge is more process related than technical. LIPS table is used to maintain Delivery information (item level, LIKP is for header level), and VBAP table is used to maintain Sales Order information (item level, VBAK is for header level).

In the Sales and Distribution process of SAP, you can create a Delivery for a Sales Order. So on LIPS-VGBEL the system will store the preceding Sales Order number (VBAP-VBELN), and on LIPS-VGPOS the system will store the preceding Sales Order item (VBAP-POSNR).

Also, there is another option to retrieve the document flow. You can check table VBFA.

This logic applies to a lot of other tables and processes.